# Are ability estimates given by ltm and mirt Z-scores?

Tags: r, item-response-theory

Are the ability estimates given by `fscores` in `mirt` and `factor.scores` in `ltm` *Z*-scores? That is, so long as the relevant ability can be assumed to be normally distributed in the population, is someone with an ability estimate of 0 estimated to be of mean ability, someone with an ability estimate of 1 estimated to be one standard deviation above mean ability, and so forth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way these scores are estimated is somewhat complicated, but I think there is no reason you can't interpret them as 'Z-scores'. So, in short, yes.